# MySql 4.1+ hash in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, mysql4

Hello I'm trying to make an ASP.Net website and I need my passwords to be stored in the database encrypted in MySql4.1+ method. I have searched the web enough but I still haven't found any tuts that can show me how to make the registration and login proccess work this way. Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.mysql41.html)

Comment: Thanks dude pretty good tip I just saw that but the problem is I don't know how to generate this in C# and call it when the function needs it... But thanks anyway :)

Comment: can't you use bcrypt or does mysql have a special type for hashes?

Comment: Well I'm basicly a newbie on programming yet but as I can tell the password needs to start with an * and then 40 characters uppercase letters or numbers for example this is "password":
*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19

Comment: Well I got it just type PASSWORD(#your pass) in the query and that's it :)